# "Sorry OneDrive can't add your folder right now" | SharePoint 2019 Sync Library

Tags: sharepoint-server, document-library, 2019, onedrive-for-business, sync

I want to sync SharePoint 2019 Site Library to local file system via OneDrive using **Sync** option of SP Library.

I have setup the configuration as per [Microsft Article](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/install/new-onedrive-sync-client) in Domain Controller.

However, after successfully executing the steps mentioned in article I tried to sync from SP Library.

Following error is encountered even though I tried to create the necessary OneDrive sync folder manually.

There is no pc/domain restriction in our OneDrive tenant admin.

**Note**: I have even followed following [article](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/odfb/sorry-onedrive-cant-add-your-folder-right-now) for troubleshooting but no luck.

Any help is much appreciated!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

1.It may be caused by the OneDrive folder on "C:". When trying to synchronize contents, OneDrive does not have permission to create new folder in "C:". So you could try to manually create the needed folder and the synchronization will work normally.

2.It may be caused by the device is on a different domain.

Reference:
[Case of the OneDrive for Business “Sorry can’t add your folder right now”](https://chentiangemalc.wordpress.com/2017/05/21/case-of-the-onedrive-for-business-sorry-cant-add-your-folder-right-now/)

3.Re-install and re-configure the OneDrive.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that your folder permissions got messed up. With a little trick I was able get it right again:

1. In SharePoint **`Sync` an arbitrary subfolder** (we will delete it later)
2. **Open it in Windows Explorer** (you should now see the "orphaned" folders and the newly synced one (if not this guide will not help you))
3. Go to the **OneDrive settings** and make sure that you remove them by clicking **stop syncing** for the broken folders
4. **Delete the "orphaned" folders** from step 2 (everyting should be clean now)
5. Go back to SharePoint and **`Sync` the** (initially broken) **folders**
6. **Remove the subfolder from step 1** (by clicking **stop syncing** + delete it in Windows Explorer)